# zendframework standard URL parameters

Tags: zend-framework, request

i have problems with the zend framework 1, i use a paywall api and it use a pingback url methode, for example:

```
myurl.com/payback?user_id=123&foo=bar...
```

But the problem is now i can't read the params in zendframework.
It work only if i do it like that

```
myurl.com/payback/user_id/123/foo/bar
```

i used different methodes to read it out:

```
$q = $this->getRequest()->getQuery();
$p = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

the request object look like that:

```
object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http)[74]
protected '_paramSources' => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string '_GET' (length=4)
  1 => string '_POST' (length=5)
protected '_requestUri' => string '/index/paywall?uid=zIhvpyVslUS5ND79AfMeBPao1LjXY2Kc&goodsid=6001&slength=&speriod=&type=0&ref=&is_test=1&sig=c62538caf7a36ea2f3a795bb3dc32c07' (length=141)
protected '_baseUrl' => string '' (length=0)
protected '_basePath' => null
protected '_pathInfo' => string '/index/paywall' (length=14)
protected '_params' => 
  array (size=3)
  'controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
  'action' => string 'paywall' (length=7)
  'module' => string 'default' (length=7)
 protected '_rawBody' => null
protected '_aliases' => 
array (size=0)
  empty
protected '_dispatched' => boolean true
protected '_module' => string 'default' (length=7)
protected '_moduleKey' => string 'module' (length=6)
protected '_controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
protected '_controllerKey' => string 'controller' (length=10)
protected '_action' => string 'paywall' (length=7)
protected '_actionKey' => string 'action' (length=6)
```

I Hope someone can help me,
thank you

Comment: can you check if it is available via `$_GET[]`

Comment: no $_GET is empty, but i fixed it now with this workaround...

    `$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`
     `parse_str($url["query"], $request_data);`